# find files that is stored in format yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a cron job that runs at 1am and  creates an index.html for yesterday and current day in the below yyyy/mm/dd format.

I need to grab day -1  and send to users. How can i achieve this?

```
-bash-4.2$ find /var/lib/pgsql/scripts/outfile/ -type f -name index.html

/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/outfile/2022/06/29/index.html 
/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/outfile/2022/06/30/index.html
```

In this case it would be

```
/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/outfile/2022/06/29/index.html
```

How can i do this using bash scripting?

Comment: On what operating system? Is this for Linux or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you need an string that express `yesterday` (assuming that today was `2022/06/30` in your example).

That could be produced by (GNU) `date` as `date -d yesterday +%Y/%m/%d` or by bash (+4.2) itself as:

```
$ printf "%(%Y/%m/%d)T" "$(($(printf "%(%s)T" -1)-86400))"
2022/06/29
```

That's assuming that a day is actually 86400 seconds and that the DST won't interfere with that.

Then, you would get the whole directory to the file as:

```
dir='/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/outfile/'
name='index.html'
yest="$(printf "%(%Y/%m/%d)T" "$(($(printf "%(%s)T" -1)-86400))")"
file="$dir$yest/$name"

[[ -e "$file" ]] || exit 3

echo "$file"
```

Please note that cron use `sh` (not `bash`), the script above must use `bash` or write the script to a file and call `bash /path/to/scriptfile` from the cron `sh`.

Comment: very useful and expands my understanding on bash. Many thanks Quartz

Comment: You are Welcome @Nick